# How to scan specific string from excel and output is as new template?

Tags: c#, string, excel, visual-studio

I have to create a EXE. file in Visual Studio 2015 C#, the exe. file have to read a excel file and select some particular column from it, and then output these particular column as a new template.

Let's say, an excel originally have Column Name, Gender, Age. 
I want to use the exe to select all the information in Column Name only, and output it as another new excel file.

Now I can read excel file and output it as another excel, but I dont know how to scan specific string from excel and output is as new template?

OP's Code from mispost:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

using Microsoft.Office.Core;

using Spire.Xls;
using Spire.Xls.Charts;

namespace Spire.Xls.Sample
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Form1.
/// </summary>
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnRun;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnPDF;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClose;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    public DataGrid dataGrid1;


    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary
    private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        // TODO: Add any constructor code after InitializeComponent call
        //
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose( bool disposing )
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            if (components != null) 
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose( disposing );
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.btnRun = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.dataGrid1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid();
        this.btnPDF = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGrid1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // btnRun
        // 
        this.btnRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(313, 494);
        this.btnRun.Name = "btnRun";
        this.btnRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(144, 30);
        this.btnRun.TabIndex = 2;
        this.btnRun.Text = "Apply filter";
        this.btnRun.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnRun_Click);
        // 
        // btnClose
        // 
        this.btnClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(633, 494);
        this.btnClose.Name = "btnClose";
        this.btnClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 30);
        this.btnClose.TabIndex = 3;
        this.btnClose.Text = "Close";
        this.btnClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClose_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(134)));
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 14);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(528, 41);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label1.Text = "This app can apply filter to Excel";
        this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // dataGrid1
        // 
        this.dataGrid1.AllowDrop = true;
        this.dataGrid1.DataMember = "Group";
        this.dataGrid1.HeaderForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
        this.dataGrid1.ImeMode = System.Windows.Forms.ImeMode.On;
        this.dataGrid1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(313, 221);
        this.dataGrid1.Name = "dataGrid1";
        this.dataGrid1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(406, 249);
        this.dataGrid1.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // btnPDF
        // 
        this.btnPDF.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(474, 494);
        this.btnPDF.Name = "btnPDF";
        this.btnPDF.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(144, 30);
        this.btnPDF.TabIndex = 6;
        this.btnPDF.Text = "Save as PDF";
        this.btnPDF.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnPDF_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleBaseSize = new System.Drawing.Size(6, 18);
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(731, 552);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnPDF);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGrid1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnClose);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnRun);
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Excel modifier";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGrid1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }


    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

        //Initailize worksheet
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        sheet.InsertDataTable((DataTable)this.dataGrid1.DataSource,true,1,1,-1,-1);

        //Sets body style
        CellStyle oddStyle = workbook.Styles.Add("oddStyle");
        oddStyle.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeLeft].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        oddStyle.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeRight].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        oddStyle.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeTop].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        oddStyle.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeBottom].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        oddStyle.KnownColor = ExcelColors.LightGreen1;

        CellStyle evenStyle = workbook.Styles.Add("evenStyle");
        evenStyle.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeLeft].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        evenStyle.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeRight].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        evenStyle.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeTop].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        evenStyle.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeBottom].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        evenStyle.KnownColor = ExcelColors.LightTurquoise;

        foreach( CellRange range in  sheet.AllocatedRange.Rows)
        {
            if (range.Row % 2 == 0)
                range.CellStyleName = evenStyle.Name;
            else
                range.CellStyleName = oddStyle.Name;
        }

        //Sets header style
        CellStyle styleHeader = sheet.Rows[0].Style;
        styleHeader.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeLeft].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        styleHeader.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeRight].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        styleHeader.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeTop].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        styleHeader.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeBottom].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
        styleHeader.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignType.Center;
        styleHeader.KnownColor = ExcelColors.Green;
        styleHeader.Font.KnownColor = ExcelColors.White;
        styleHeader.Font.IsBold = true;

        sheet.AllocatedRange.AutoFitColumns();
        sheet.AllocatedRange.AutoFitRows();

        sheet.Rows[0].RowHeight = 20;

        //Writes filter data
        //CreateFilterData(sheet);
        sheet.AutoFilters.Range = sheet.Range["A1:Z1"];

        //append the sort column index and order by attributes 
        //workbook.DataSorter.SortColumns.Add(2, OrderBy.Ascending);
        //workbook.DataSorter.SortColumns.Add(3, OrderBy.Ascending);

        //set the range to sort.
        //workbook.DataSorter.Sort(sheet["A1:Z999"]);

        //save the xls to this path
        workbook.SaveToFile(@"C:\Users\SmartEducationCoLtd\Desktop\sample.xls");
        ExcelDocViewer( workbook.FileName );



    //private void CreateFilterData(Worksheet sheet)
    //{ }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

        //load from this excel path
        workbook.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\SmartEducationCoLtd\Desktop\DataTableSample.xls");
        //Initailize worksheet
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        this.dataGrid1.DataSource =  sheet.ExportDataTable();
    }


    private void ExcelDocViewer( string fileName )
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
        }
        catch{}
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say you can read an excel file, what type do you retrieve it as? Post some code of what you've done and we can try retrieving string information from it.

Comment: An excel file with three column (Name(string), Gender(string), Age(string)), and in each column are e.g. Jason(string), M(string), 22(int)

Comment: I use using Spire.Xls; to read an excel file and output it as another new excel file

Comment: I posted my entire code below

Answer (score 0):

You've set the data to the `DataSource` of your `DataGrid` to the data from the excel file via the line:

```
this.dataGrid1.DataSource =  sheet.ExportDataTable();
```

in

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
```

You could use the data directly from here, but I'm guessing you want to use it in this function:

```
 private void btnRun_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
```

You're accessing the `DataTable` you saved earlier using: `(DataTable)this.dataGrid1.DataSource` in the line: `sheet.InsertDataTable((DataTable)this.dataGrid1.DataSource,true,1,1,-1,-1);`. You could simply set it to a `datatable` variable using:

```
var dt = (DataTable)this.dataGrid1.DataSource;
```

OR set it a local instance level variable in the `Form_Load` method when you're setting the `Datagrid`'s `DataSource` in the first place.

However you do it, once you have the `datatable`, you can access it using:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{ 
  string name = row["Name"].ToString();
  string gender = row["Gender"].ToString();
  string age= row["Age"].ToString();
}
```

or whatever you want to with the data.